# Shows an error when using the Gate facade

Tags: laravel

When writing privileges and rights of a user shows error: `403
Forbidden`

Controller code

```
class IndexController extends AdminController
{
    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

        if (Gate::denies('VIEW_ADMIN')) {
            abort(403);
        }

        $this->template = env('THEME').'.admin.index';
 }
```

AuthServiceProvider code

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

   Gate::define('VIEW_ADMIN', function($user){
        return $user->canDo('VIEW_ADMIN');
    });

    //
}
```

Model User code

The `User` model is associated with the `Roles` model, and the `Roles` model is associated with the `Permission` model.

```
public function canDo($permission, $require = FALSE){

    if (is_array($permission)) {
        dump($permission);
    }
    else{
        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
           foreach ($this->permissions as $permission) {
               if (str_is($permission,$permission->name)) {
                   return true;
               }
           }
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: what your foreach does? The $role is unused. And also if you return true so you should return false too because return type should be boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You rewrite input `$permission` on line `foreach ($this->permissions as $permission) {` so your `if (str_is($permission,$permission->name))` is always FALSE 
because

```
str_is(array(), 'VIEW_ADMIN') === FALSE
```

You should do this

```
public function canDo($permission, $require = FALSE){

    if (is_array($permission)) {
        dump($permission);
    }
    else{
        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
           foreach ($this->permissions as $permissionObject) {
               if (str_is($permission,$permissionObject->name)) {
                   return true;
               }
           }
        }
    }        
}
```

Also you should **add** return **FALSE** because return type is **boolean** in this case.

Comment: I did this:  public function canDo($permission, $require = FALSE){

        if (is_array($permission)) {
            dump($permission);
        }
        else{
            foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
               foreach ($this->permissions as $permission) {
                   if (str_is('VIEW_ADMIN',$permission->name)) {
                       return true;
                   }else{
                    return false;
                   }
               }
            }
        }
        
    }
 the same error

Comment: @Soib You need rename $permission variable they are overriding. For example in foreach rename to  foreach ($this->permissions as $permissionObject).

Comment: str_is is what .. that should be Str::is() ? And check permission and permissionObject->name .. if aren't equal so its not error but truth.